# Give Truncate permission on Vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a set of tables I've created for which I want to give somebody else permission to truncate and add rows

I gave permission via this command:

```
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT  ON TABLE temp.TableName TO Public
```

But when the other permission tries to truncate it, they are getting error of **Permission Denied**.

Is there any other permission that I need to give?

Answer (score 2):

What if you include `TRUNCATE` in the list?

```
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT, TRUNCATE ON TABLE temp.TableName TO Public
```

Presumably, you would also want `DELETE`, unless you intend that users can delete *all* the rows, but not some of them.  You don't need `UPDATE` unless you want users to be able to modify values as well.